# Zerobrane hotkeys to jump between editor tabs and other panes within IDE

Tags: zerobrane

Using Zerobrane, are there any defined hotkeys or keymaps that will jump between panes within the IDE?  Like, some key to jump between several files open as tabs (jump between tabs).  Another is jumping from editor tab pane over to the project pane, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To jump between tabs you can you `Ctrl-PgUp/PgDn` or `Ctrl-(Shift-)Tab`. Also, `Ctrl-P` will open a command panel with the list of currently open files, and after selecting a file from the list press `Enter` to jump to the tab with that file.

Jumping to Project tab and Console is not available, but moving between tabs there can be done using the same `Ctrl-PgUp/PgDn` combination. I'll consider adding some hotkey to move between open panes.

Update 7/13: Something like this may work as a simple workaround (add to the IDE config file as `Edit > Preferences > Settings: User`):

```
ide:SetHotKey(function()ide:GetProjectTree():SetFocus()end, "Ctrl-Alt-P")
ide:SetHotKey(function()ide:GetOutlineTree():SetFocus()end, "Ctrl-Alt-O")
```

Other panes (Output/`GetOutput()`, Console/`GetConsole()`, etc.) can be done in a similar way.

Comment: Much appreciated!  After years (and years) of not using the mouse for editing, it’s just hard to break the habit.  But I love the lightweight footprint of the IDE, it works great in the VM on my ipad

Comment: That does work for getting from the tab over to the Outline/Project pane.  But now I was trying to use Ctrl-P to get back over to the tabs, but it didn’t open a command panel with the list of currently open files.  I will have to investigate that.  Thanks again for your help.